# How to upgrade MBP early 2015 SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade

I am trying to look for a way to upgrade my **13 inch Macbook Pro Retina** SSD because it's too small right now (only 128GB).

I found out that currently it seems only **OWC Aura** offers the upgrade SSD for this model; are there any other brands that you know offers upgrade for **2015 early MBP**?

Note: I'm trying to install Windows with bootcamp, so external drives aren't really options for me.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ordered and installed the new SSD product from OWC for upgrading that specific model of MacBook Pro.

The ordering process was simple, payment went through without problems and the drive was delivered 2 days later even though I'm in Europe. The package came with great instructions and even the necessary screwdrivers.

On the other hand, the SSD is slower than the Apple supplied SSD and it simply doesn't support Bootcamp presently.

Your only option for installing Windows is to run only Windows on the MacBook Pro - that works with the OWC SSD. You can ofcourse run OS X and a hypervisor such as VMware, VirtualBox or Parallels to run Windows on top of OS X.

There is currently no other brand (except Apple) supplying a compatible disk.

Answer (score 1):

I've bought a number of OWC products include SSD's for older MBP and MBA models. Always been satisfied.

That said, I recall reading a review that said there was a problem installing Bootcamp on the latest upgrades so I'd check with OWC tech support before ordering.